# Limits - a different approach

Tags: limits

$\lim_{x \to\infty }(\frac{x^3+4x^2+3x+5}{x^2+2x+3}+lx+m)=10$.

How do I calculate the value of l and m?

**My try**: *I know questions having limit tending to infinity can be solved by dividing the numerator and denominator by greatest power of $x$.But it got me nowhere in this question. Any help appreciated.*

Comment: Re-check your question before posting. You have a $n$ and a $x.$ What's correct ?

Comment: Please take a look at a similar questions for which I had given an answer a while back. It should help you. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166116/long-limit-question/1166131#1166131

Answer (score 4):

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}(\frac{x^3+4x^2+3x+5}{x^2+2x+3}+lx+m)=10$$

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}(\frac{x^3+4x^2+3x+5+lx^3+2lx^2+3lx+mx^2+2mx+3m}{x^2+2x+3})=10$$

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}(\frac{(1+l)x^3+(4+2l+m)x^2+(3+l+2m)x+(5+3m)}{x^2+2x+3})=10$$

Note that as the limit exists, the coefficient of $x^3$ has to be $0$, so we get $l=-1$

And also the ratio of the leading coefficient ($x^2$)$=10$, so we get $4+2l+m=10$ and thus $m=8$

Comment: An explanation for the downvote? I think this is a correct solution, so I would like to hear the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Using the long division, you have $$\frac{x^3+4 x^2+3 x+5}{x^2+2 x+3}=x+2-\frac{4}{x}+\cdots$$ So $$\lim_{x \to\infty }\left(\frac{x^3+4x^2+3x+5}{x^2+2x+3}+lx+m\right)=\lim_{x \to\infty }(x+2+lx+m)=10$$ from which you can conclude that $l=-1$ and $m=8$.

Answer (score 1):

If this limit is $10$, then the limit when you divide by $x$ is $0$: so
$$
\lim_{x \to\infty }\left(\frac{x^3+4x^2+3x+5}{x(x^2+2x+3)}+l+\frac{m}{x}\right)=0
$$
Therefore $1+l=0$; now
$$
\lim_{x \to\infty }\left(\frac{x^3+4x^2+3x+5}{x^2+2x+3}-x+m\right)=
\lim_{x \to\infty }\left(\frac{2x^2+5}{x^2+2x+3}+m\right)=2+m
$$

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, we have
$$\lim_{x\to\infty }\left(\frac{x^3+4x^2+3x+5}{x^2+2x+3}-[-lx+10-m]\right)=0$$.
$$-l=\lim_{x\to\infty }\frac{\frac{x^3+4x^2+3x+5}{x^2+2x+3}}{x}=1$$
thus
$l=-1$
and 
$$10-m=\lim_{x\to\infty }\left(\frac{x^3+4x^2+3x+5}{x^2+2x+3}-x\right)=2$$
therefore $m=8$

Comment: Why down vote? My solution is correct.

Comment: Indeed, $-lx+10-m$ is Oblique asymptote.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote

Comment: I think your answer is correct as is the answer of @user362325 below. I cannot explain the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x \to\infty }\left(\dfrac{x^3+4x^2+3x+5}{x^2+2x+3}+\ell x + m\right)=10$$

$$\lim_{x \to\infty }\left(\dfrac{x^3+4x^2+3x+5}{x^2+2x+3}+\ell x\right)=10-m$$

$$\lim_{x \to\infty }\left(x + \dfrac{2x^2+5}{x^2+2x+3}+\ell x\right)=10-m$$

$$\lim_{x \to\infty }(x +\ell x)=0 \implies \ell = -1$$

$$\lim_{x \to\infty }\left(\dfrac{2x^2+5}{x^2+2x+3}\right)=10-m
\implies 2=10-m \implies m=8$$

Answer (score -1):

$\dfrac{x^3+4x^2+3x+5}{x^2+2x+3} \approx_{\infty} x\implies \lim_{x \to \infty} (x+lx+m) = 10\implies l = -1, m = 10.$

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to\infty }\left(\frac{x^3+4x^2+3x+5}{x^2+2x+3}-x+10 \right)=12$$